# How to align a QTimer interval with the system time

Tags: python-3.x, time, pyqt5, qtimer

How do I start my function every 5 minutes and 20 seconds? I used:

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
self.timer.start(310000)
```

But I'd like to set it by the time of my PC - so if I start the program at 3:23, the update track is at 3:25:20, 3:30:20 etc.

Comment: change `310000` to `5 * 60 * 1000 +  20 * 1000`

Comment: thanks,In any case, if I run at 23:27 the update will be at 23:32:20, 23:37:20
I would like it to be at 23:30:20, 23:35:20.
I take my data from the internet and it is updated every 5min

Comment: Then calculate the time to be the first time X you want, and when it is that moment you just fire the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two timers are needed for this: a single-shot to get to the starting point, which then triggers a second timer which times-out every 5 minutes (at the 20th second). The starting point can be calculated with [QDateTime.msecsTo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#msecsTo), so the code would look something like this:

```
mins = 5
secs = 20
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
self.timer.setInterval(mins * 60 * 1000)
def start_point():
    self.timer.timeout.emit()
    self.timer.start()
d1 = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTimeUtc()
d2 = QtCore.QDateTime(d1)
t1 = d1.time()
d2.setTime(QtCore.QTime(t1.hour(), t1.minute(), secs))
if t1.second() > secs:
    d2 = d2.addSecs((mins - t1.minute() % mins) * 60)
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(d1.msecsTo(d2), start_point)
```

Note that the accuracy of this depends on the system clock, and there will also be a fraction of a second lag whilst the start point is calculated - so don't expect it to stay perfectly in sync with the network time. If you need it to run for a long time, you could check the current time in `updateplot` and restart the timer if it starts to drift beyond a certain threshold.

**UPDATE**:

Here's a demo that uses the above approach:

[image]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.spinMins = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinMins.setRange(0, 59)
        self.spinMins.setValue(1)
        self.spinSecs = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinSecs.setRange(0, 59)
        self.spinSecs.setValue(5)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.resetTimer)
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.edit.setReadOnly(True)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinMins, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinSecs, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 2)
        self.mainTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.mainTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateplot)
        self.startTimer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.startTimer.setSingleShot(True)
        def start_point():
            self.mainTimer.timeout.emit()
            self.mainTimer.start()
        self.startTimer.timeout.connect(start_point)
        self.resetTimer()

    def resetTimer(self):
        self.mainTimer.stop()
        self.startTimer.stop()
        mins = self.spinMins.value()
        secs = self.spinSecs.value()
        self.edit.append('restarting timer... (%dm %ds)' % (mins, secs))
        self.mainTimer.setInterval(mins * 60 * 1000)
        d1 = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTimeUtc()
        d2 = QtCore.QDateTime(d1)
        t1 = d1.time()
        d2.setTime(QtCore.QTime(t1.hour(), t1.minute(), secs))
        if t1.second() > secs:
            d2 = d2.addSecs((mins - t1.minute() % mins) * 60)
        self.startTimer.start(d1.msecsTo(d2))

    def updateplot(self, t=None):
        t = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        self.edit.append('timeout: %s' % t.toString('HH:mm:ss.zzz'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('Timer Test')
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 300, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ekhumoro if I've understood the question correctly, the OP wants the timer to timeout every 5 minutes, *at* the n*5th minute and 20 seconds of the hour.

Comment: @musicamante Right, thanks. That's why I put the mins/secs in two variables - but I obviously forgot to change the interval calculation. (PS: and I can now see my problem description was wrong as well - should all be fixed now, though).

Comment: @ekhumoro sorry to bother you again. I just realized that there's another issue with your answer: if the minute is greater than `60 - mins`, you'll get an invalid QTime (since it only accepts a 0-59 range). And even if you take care of that, you'll need to add the 23 hours + 1 exception.

Comment: @musicamante Damn, you're right - what a botch job. I broke my golden rule of never posting answers without writing a full test case first, so I've got no excuses. I will re-write it ASAP.

Comment: @ekhumoro don't worry, we all do that from time to time :-) In the meantime I've posted an alternate answer that takes care of that too (but using a class approach), I hope you don't mind...

Comment: @musicamante My mistake was using `QTime` instead of `QDateTime`, and not using the proper API to add the time delta. Hopefully that is all fixed now, but if you can see any other issues, please let me know.

Comment: I thought about using QDateTime at first too, but I was afraid that there would be some problems involving the daylight saving time, so I decided for the QTime approach with the minute/hour "exceptions". Interestingly enough, QDateTime's msecsTo implementation takes care of that, but I'm afraid that it only works for zones that [un]set the daylight time "outside" the +-2 hour midnight range and there could be problems if the change happens between 23:00 and 1:00 (yeah, timezones are crap). I believe that QTime completely ignoring daylight is actually a blessing for these situations.

Comment: @musicamante Yes, I did consider DST, but I assumed the behaviour of `addSecs` and `msecsTo` would be more conveniently aligned. However, a little more investigation has revealed that this is not always true. I suppose the simplest way to finesse these issues is to use UTC, since (in this particular case) only the minutes and seconds are relevant.

Comment: yes, I agree that using UTC might be a good choice (but, considering the situation, the CPU load wouldn't be that big issue as soon as we use a case check to ensure that minute/hour ranges do not exceed). Nonetheless, a small (*possible future*) issue still exists: right now QDateTime doesn't account for leap seconds; while at this time they seem to always be positive (and I think that'd make things easier), it could change in the future. I know I'm really talking about very specific uncommon cases (just pointing at the proboscis of the elephant in the room). But, what if...? :-)

Comment: @musicamante I was going to make a comment about leap seconds, but decided enough was enough. Another possibility is that some country may decide to start using DST offsets that aren't whole hours (it's [actually happened before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B07:20)).

Answer (score 1):

I've had some experience with this kind of timers, as I developed a personal "to do" program for my own purposes with custom reminders that fire up at specific intervals which have offsets that are "hour/minute sensitive".
After some struggling, I realized that the best approach is to subclass and implement your own timer; while this kind of implementation might seem a bit of an overshoot on first look, I believe that it can be a real time saver.

The most important aspects to take care of is ensuring that the timer is always aligned with the system clock and, obviously, get the time intervals as much correct as possible. To achieve that, instead of a continuous timer, I chose a *`singleShot` set timer* that sets its interval at each timeout. Since we can assume that this kind of intervals use high values (usually greater than a minute), computing the interval at each timeout is not a big issue, CPU-wise.

```
class SpecialTimer(QtCore.QTimer):
    publicTimeout = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, minutes=5, offsetSecs=20):
        super().__init__(singleShot=True)
        assert isinstance(minutes, int) and 0 < minutes < 60 and not 60 % minutes, \
            '"minutes" can only be a no-remainder-int-modulus of 60 (5, 6, 10, etc.)'
        self.minutes = minutes
        # offset can be greater than 60 secs: you might want to use a 5 minutes
        # interval, but emit the timeout at a 2 minute offset (23:02, 23:07, etc);
        # nonetheless that offset should always be < minutes * 60
        self.offsetMins, self.offsetSecs = divmod(offsetSecs, 60)
        assert self.offsetMins < minutes, 'offset has to be less than minutes'
        self.offsetMins %= minutes

        # "swap" the base timeout signal with a custom one; while this isn't
        # really necessary, it helps to keep a cleaner implementation, as calling
        # "QTimer.timeout.disconnect()" would disconnect the restart slot too;
        # in this way you can safely and transparently [dis]connect the "timeout"
        # signal while keeping its functionality in the meantime.
        self._timeout = self.timeout
        self._timeout.connect(self.start)
        self.timeout = self.publicTimeout
        self._timeout.connect(self.timeout)

    def start(self, *args):
        current = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
        nextMinute = current.minute() + self.minutes - current.minute() % self.minutes
        nextMinute += self.offsetMins
        nextHour = current.hour()
        # take care of minute >= 60 and hour >= 24 exceptions, as QTime only
        # accepts 0-59 minute range and 0-23 hour range
        if nextMinute >= 60:
            nextMinute %= 60
            nextHour += 1
            nextHour %= 24
        nextTimeout = QtCore.QTime(nextHour, nextMinute, self.offsetSecs)
        # check the nextTimeout, as the minute/second offset could make a first
        # interval greater than it should be, which will result in skipping the
        # first possible timeout
        if nextTimeout.addSecs(-self.minutes * 60) > current:
            nextTimeout = nextTimeout.addSecs(-self.minutes * 60)
        # if the next timeout happens after midnight, "msecsTo" will return a
        # negative value, let's use the % modulus to get a positive value
        super().start(current.msecsTo(nextTimeout) % 86400000)
```